# Where can I find breaking changes in chart.js in early versions?

Tags: chart.js

I have a huge MVC project that uses chart.js but it is version 1.0.2 which has [CVE-2020-7746](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2020-7746) vulnerability and needs to be updated to at least 2.9.4 but I need to know if there are any breaking changes in that huge jump. Where can I easily find all breaking changes in that jump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look through all the releases from 2.0 alpha to release 2.0 to see al breaking changes

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases?page=10